# Why this code is not working? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

i'm learning cpp and need some help.
My code is not working, it stops at `add->value = value`.

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;  
};

node *top; 

int insert(int value){
    struct node *add;
    cout<< "here it stops";
    add->value = value;
    add->next = NULL;

    if(top == NULL ){
        top == add;
    }else{
        add->next = top;
        top =  add;
    }  
}
```

Comment: `add` is not initialised, so it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure that's C++? It looks like C to me.

Comment: For C++, you don't need the typedef, and you don't need to repeat `struct` when declaring. If you are going to learn "C++ as a better C", use the benefits.

Comment: Try this linked list tutorial:
http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/linkedlist.php#linkedlistexample1

Comment: For reference, next time include the error/warning the compiler throws (or mention that it did not issue any if that's the case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
struct node *add;
```

you are defining a pointer to a `node` (you can omit the `struct` here). But the pointer doesn't point to any valid `node` object. You must make it point to a `node` before you can do this:

```
add->value = value;
```

Comment: In fact, the irony is that he's **not** initializing a pointer to a node.

Comment: "Defining" != "initialising", @juan.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Correct, but it is doing both. Edited anyway.

Comment: @sehe Right he's *default initializing it*, which doesn't do much good.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, fine, but we don't usually consider default initialisation of a pointer to be "initialisation" in any meaningful sense, and certainly not when the entire problem is that he didn't perform meaningful initialisation! Or, to be picky, _the OP_ really isn't initialising anything, since default initialisation is performed for him.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, they could have validly initialized the pointer to `nullptr`. It would still be UB to de-reference it. But I agree, "initialization" is a confusing word in this context.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah, well, they didn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

Before you do add->value = value, you need to allocate space for struct node *add (something like add = new node()).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allocate memory to which pointer add will point to.

Also your function returns nothing though it has return type int.

The function could look the following way

```
void insert( int value )
{
    node *add = new node;

    add->value = value;
    add->next = top;

    top =  add;
}
```

Or if your compiler supports list initialization then

```
void insert( int value )
{
    node *add = new node { value, top };

    top =  add;
}
```

Or in one line :)

```
inline void insert( int value ) { top = new node { value, top }; }
```